# Beamer - define highlight color

Tags: beamer, color

I am using Beamer for the first time. I use `setbeamercolor` to change most of the colors of the `miniframes` and so on. But how to I change the color of the highlighted text in the headline and table of content. Right now it is bright green.

```
\documentclass[xcolor=dvipsnames,compress,12pt]{beamer}%
\mode<presentation>

%% General document %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%

%% Beamer Layout %%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\useoutertheme[subsection=false,shadow]{miniframes}
\usecolortheme{seahorse}
\usecolortheme{rose}
\usefonttheme{serif}
```

Comment: Could you provide a complete example?  With that preamble, I don't get any green.  What other things are you setting?

Answer (score 4):

To change theme-specific highlighting colours then, in addition to the settings applied by `\usecolortheme`, you can use specific `\setbeamercolor` commands such as:

```
\setbeamercolor{section in toc shaded}{fg=red}
\setbeamercolor{section in toc}{fg=blue}
```

to change the colour of text in the table of contents (assuming by 'highlighted' you mean 'not shaded'?) and

```
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=red}
```

to change the colour of section text in the headline.

See section 17 of the [beamer user guide](ftp://ftp.dante.de/pub/tex/macros/latex/.../beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) and [beamercolorthemedefault.sty](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/.../beamercolorthemedefault.sty) for more details on colours and the names of areas/characters that can be specified. The latter also indicates the parent/child relationships.

Comment: Thank you Andrew and Mas! I used \hypersetup{colorlinks=true,anchorcolor=yellow,linkcolor=green,menucolor=cyan} and therefore my TOC text was green. Now its white or black depending on the background.